# Given cell number how do you calculate efficiently which row and column it is in

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose there are 5 columns and 7 rows. So there are total of 35 cells. By cell you could think of excel cells..

If i tell you to tell me about cell 20's row number and column number how would you tell me.

Optional the numbering starts from zero...so columns are like 0,1,2,3...

Comment: $\frac{20}5$  row, $(20\%5) +1$ column

Comment: can you explain this

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for cell $n$'s column number for instance, then you don't care whether $n$ is 0,5,10, etc. These all refer to the same column. Cells 0,5,10,15, etc belong to one column. Cells 1,6,11,16 etc belong to the one column. What matters is what $n$ is equal to after you take out all the multiples of 5. So try using $modulo$ to take out multiples of 5. Do the same for $n$'s row number using the $modulo$ and you're on your way.